# The output of this code block doesn't make sense to me

Tags: c#, virtual-functions

The runtime type of all the calling instances is D hence, all the invocations of F() should be the F() method declared in D.

```
using System;
class A
{
   public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("A.F"); }
}
class B: A
{
   public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("B.F"); }
}
class C: B
{
   new public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("C.F"); }
}
class D: C
{
   public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("D.F"); }
}
class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      D d = new D();
      A a = d;
      B b = d;
      C c = d;
      a.F();
      b.F();
      c.F();
      d.F();
   }
}
```

the output is:

```
B.F
B.F
D.F
D.F
```

Shouldn't the output be:

```
D.F
D.F
D.F
D.F
```

Comment: You should edit question title to much the problem

Answer (score 7):

[Versioning with the Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the method in the derived class is preceded with the new keyword,
>   the method is defined as being independent of the method in the base
>   class.

So you'r `F` methods from `A` and `B` are not *connected* with these from `C` and `D`, and that's why you get what you get.

At runtime CLR looks for `virtual` method implementation that should be used starting from type the variables is declared to be up to type it really is. For `a.F()` and `b.F()` it stops on `B.F()` declaration, because `C.F()` is a different method (because of `new`).

Answer (score 1):

It should not...

```
A a = d;
```

This means you are creating a class of type `A`. And since you are explicitly overriding the related method in class `B`; `A` employs the method in the `B` class.

On the otherhand, in this line;

```
new public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("C.F"); }
```

You are declaring that you will not use the `F()` method from base by using the `new` keyword.

If you had overriden the `F()` method in `D` and `C` classes, all instance would have called the `F()` method declared in `D` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `new public virtual void F()` in class C:B. It means that the `F()` in class `C` and the `F()` in class `B` are different method.

So when you override `C` to class `D`, the method `F()` in class `D` is overwritten from class `C`, not `B`.

Another obvious example can be like this:

```
  C c = new C();
  B b = c;
  b.F();
  c.F();
```

Comment: But the runtime type of all the calling instances is D, which means the implementation of F() in D is the one that's invoked.

Comment: Not exactly until the method `F()` is overridden. If you use `new` instead, it will be handled as a new method, not an overridden

Comment: Got it! And because the closest implementation to the caller type at runtime, in this case the F() in B for a.F();
      b.F(); and F() in D for c.F();
      d.F();, is called.

Comment: True. Just consider that c.F() is a new method instead an inherited one.